# Spark Job taking long time to append data to S3

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm running spark job on EMR and trying to convert large zipped file (15gb) to parquet but it is taking too long to write to S3.

I'm using r5 instance for master (1 instance) and core (3 instances).
Here is my code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date

def main():
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("csv-to-parquer-convertor") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalogimplementation", "hive") \
        .config("hive.metastore.connect.retries", 3) \
        .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
        .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()   

    tgt_filename = 'SOME_Prefix'
    src_path = 'SOURCE_S3_PATH'
    tgt_path = 'TARGET_ BUCKET' + tgt_filename 

    df = spark.read.csv(src_path, header=True)
    partitioned_df = df.repartition(50)
    partitioned_df.write.mode('append').parquet(path=tgt_path)
    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

any suggestion will be much appreciated. ?

Comment: Why need the repartition things?

Comment: i'm new to Spark and i heard it's good to have partitions. does partition the reasoning of slow processing?